# Call of overloaded function taking unsigned int or a pointer is ambiguous when passing integer literal 0

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading, overload-resolution

What does this error message mean?

```
error: call of overloaded ‘setval(int)’ is ambiguous
huge.cpp:18: note: candidates are: void huge::setval(unsigned int)
huge.cpp:28: note:                 void huge::setval(const char*)
```

My code looks like this:

```cpp
class huge {
private:
    unsigned char data[8];
public:
    void setval(unsigned int) { /* .... */ }
    void setval(const char *) { /* ... */ }
};

int main() {
    huge p;
    p.setval(0);
}
```

Comment: I guess the answer to this question would depend on which version of the function you ARE trying to call.  I could assume, but clearly I can't be sure either way unless you tell me.  Would that work with the compiler I wonder...

Comment: @KonradRudolph The literal `0` is a valid value for both `unsigned int` and `const char *`.

Comment: @RyanP Yeah, I'm generally aware. No idea what I meant back then.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The literal `0` has two meanings in C++.
On the one hand, it is an integer with the value 0.
On the other hand, it is a null-pointer constant.

As your `setval` function can accept either an `int` or a `char*`, the compiler can not decide which overload you meant.

The easiest solution is to just cast the `0` to the right type.
Another option is to ensure the `int` overload is preferred, for example by making the other one a template:

```
class huge
{
 private:
  unsigned char data[BYTES];
 public:
  void setval(unsigned int);
  template <class T> void setval(const T *); // not implemented
  template <> void setval(const char*);
};
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to include the specialization outside of the class declaration. Basically include `template <> void huge::setval(const char*);` just below your class declaration.  If I didn't, I received an error about specializing the template in the class scope.

Great trick though, this has stumped me before with some of my interfaces.

Comment: `0` has only one meaning in C++. It is an integer literal of the type `int`. If the OP really had an overload taking an `int` and another taking a `char*`, the overload resolution would succeed and chose the `int` overload. However, OP uses `unsigned int` as the parameter type. And those two conversions, `int` -> `unsigned int` vs null pointer constant -> `char*` are ambiguous.

Comment: @dyp: If `0` has only one meaning, how can it be involved in two ambiguous conversions with different starting types?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean with "starting types". The type of `0` is `int`. An `int` can be converted to an `unsigned int`. A constant expression of type `int` that evaluates to `0` can also be converted to any pointer type. For example, g++ and clang++ accept `1-1` as a valid null pointer constant (though clang++ only in C++03 mode). That is, `0` is not special, it simply fulfils the conditions to enable those two separate conversions.

Comment: What about if I cast and it still complains that it's ambiguous? I have a struct declaration with a constructor, and it claims to be ambiguous between the constructor and the actual `struct Thing {` line?

Comment: @AaronFranke: That might be worth a new question.

Answer (score 18):

The solution is very simple if we consider the type of the constant value, which should be "unsigned int" instead of "int".

Instead of:

```
setval(0)
```

Use:

```
setval(0u)
```

The suffix "u" tell the compiler this is a unsigned integer. Then, no conversion would be needed, and the call will be unambiguous.

Comment: Best answer, simple and elegant way to tell the compiler

Answer (score 3):

replace `p.setval(0);` with the following.

```
const unsigned int param = 0;
p.setval(param);
```

That way it knows for sure which type the constant 0 is.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
p.setval(static_cast<const char *>(0));
```

or

```
p.setval(static_cast<unsigned int>(0));
```

As indicated by the error, the type of `0` is `int`.  This can just as easily be cast to an `unsigned int` or a `const char *`.  By making the cast manually, you are telling the compiler which overload you want.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the value so the compiler knows which function to call:

```
p.setval(static_cast<const char *>( 0 ));
```

Note, that you have a segmentation fault in your code after you get it to compile (depending on which function you really wanted to call).

Answer (score 1):

That is ambiguous because a pointer is just an address, so an `int` can also be treated as a pointer – 0 (an `int`) can be converted to `unsigned int` or `char *` equally easily.

The short answer is to call `p.setval()` with something that's unambiguously one of the types it's implemented for: `unsigned int` or `char *`.  `p.setval(0U)`, `p.setval((unsigned int)0)`, and `p.setval((char *)0)` will all compile.

It's generally a good idea to stay out of this situation in the first place, though, by not defining overloaded functions with such similar types.

Comment: Can't wait for C++0x, when we'll finally have the nullptr keyword :)

Comment: p.setval((char *)0) will compile, but application crashes. p.setval(0U) works fine