# ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading, static-cast

I have two functions:

```
void DoSomething( const tchar* apsValue )
void DoSomething( size_t aiValue )
```

Now I want to pass '0' as a size_t:

```
DoSomething(0);
```

The compiler throws an error: "ambiguous call to overloaded function"

To solve this, I can use static_cast, for instance:

```
DoSomething(static_cast<size_t>(0));
```

Or simple:

```
DoSomething(size_t(0));
```

Is one of them better than the other? Are there any other approaches to solve this?

Comment: static_cast is anytime better than c-style cast, where it is applicable.

Comment: @iammilind size_t(0) isn't a c-style cast. It constructs a new size_t with '0' as value

Comment: @iammilind Why?  `static_cast` is preferable to a C style cast where there may be an issue of what type the C style cast resolves to: for pointers or references.  Otherwise... would you write `static_cast< MyClass >( 42 )` or `MyClass( 42 )`, when you want a temporary instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: In this specific case, you might be able to write `DoSomething(0u)` for the size_t, but that is not a general solution for similar cases.

Comment: @JamesKanze, `...where it is applicable`

Comment: @MrLister, `DoSomething(0ul)` or `DoSomething(0ull)`, depending on the build target. Messy, isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call of overloaded function is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672152/call-of-overloaded-function-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's ambiguous because `0` has type `int`, not `size_t`.  It can convert
to either `size_t` or a pointer, so if you have an overload of both,
it's ambiguous.  In general, I would recommend that if you have
overloaded functions, and one of them can take an integral type, you add
an overload for `int`, maybe along the lines of:

```
inline void DoSomething( int aiValue )
{
    DoSomething( static_cast<size_t>( aiValue ) );
}
```

Integral literals have type `int` by default (unless they're too big to
fit into an `int`), and by providing an exact match, you avoid any
ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for ambiguity: `NULL` has the numeric value `0`.

If in case you want `void DoSomething( const tchar* apsValue )` when passing `0` as the parameter, `nullptr` will be helpful.
Check this [What exactly is nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)

Comment: But `NULL` isn't the cause of the ambiguity in this question; `0` is. The new `nullptr` won't help here since the goal was never to call the pointer version of the function anyway.

Comment: Agreed! But the compiler is finding it ambiguous because it could be NULL's value or just `int` whose value is `0`. I will try rephrasing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>
using namespace std;

void DoSomething( char const* apsValue ) { cout << "ptr" << endl; }
void DoSomething( size_t aiValue ) { cout << "int" << endl;}

template< class Type > Type runtime_value( Type v ) { return v; }
int null() { return 0; }
template< class Type > Type* nullPointerValue() { return 0; }

int main()
{
    // Calling the integer argument overload:
    int dummy = 0;
    DoSomething( size_t() );
    DoSomething( runtime_value( 0 ) );
    DoSomething( null( ) );
    DoSomething( dummy );
    static_cast< void(*)( size_t ) >( DoSomething )( 0 );

    // Calling the pointer argument overload:
    DoSomething( nullptr );
    DoSomething( nullPointerValue<char>() );
    static_cast< void(*)( char const* ) >( DoSomething )( 0 );
}
```

It might seem surprising that this works, but it's not just implicit type conversion at work. It's also that a *compile time constant* 0 of integral type converts implicitly to nullpointer. E.g., the `null()` function avoids that because the result is not a compile time constant.