# error: call of overloaded function ambiguous

Tags: c++, stl, ambiguous

I am trying to compile [ustl](https://github.com/msharov/ustl) C++ library with MinGW GCC compiler on Windows 10.

The 41st line in the C++ header below was able to solve thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672152/call-of-overloaded-function-is-ambiguous/4673320), but there is a problem at line 43. How should I solve it?

https://github.com/msharov/ustl/blob/master/fstream.h#L41

```
    // int          ioctl (const char* rname, int request, long argument = 0);   // orig
    int         ioctl (const char* rname, int request, long argument = 0u);
    inline int      ioctl (const char* rname, int request, int argument)    { return fstream::ioctl (rname, request, long(argument)); }
    inline int      ioctl (const char* rname, int request, void* argument)  { return fstream::ioctl (rname, request, intptr_t(argument)); }
```

MinGW GCC compiler (10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)) error message:

```
fstream.h:43:132: error: call of overloaded 'ioctl(const char*&, int&, uintptr_t)' is ambiguous
    43 |     inline int  ioctl (const char* rname, int request, void* argument) { return fstream::ioctl (rname, request, uintptr_t(argument)); }
```

--
Edit: Thanks for the hint.
With [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640423/error-cast-from-void-to-int-loses-precision), below code works for me:

https://github.com/msharov/ustl/blob/master/fstream.h#L43

```
 // ... intptr_t(argument));  // orig
 *((long*)(argument)));
```

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the definition (e.g. what is `uintptr_t` in ustl?) - and I'm not inclined to trawl through all source of the ustl library to find out.  I suspect the ustl code assumes some types are distinct, but they are not with mingw (e.g. `int` and `long` can be different types with some compilers, but not on others - which can cause ambiguity if a function has both `int` and `long` (or `int *` and `long *`) overloads).  This is a common portability gotcha for library developers. Anyway, why not use the C++ standard library shipped by your compiler? It supersedes the STL.

Comment: @Peter because i can! :P curiosity, want to see more smaller code to test myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find in the last few words that

fstream.h:43:132: error: call of overloaded 'ioctl(const char*&, int&, uintptr_t)' is ambiguous 43 | inline int ioctl (const char* rname, int request, void* argument) { return fstream::ioctl (rname, request, **`uintptr_t`**(argument)); }

`intptr_t` is actually a `uintptr_t` in your environment. And as for `uintptr_t`, you can find in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) that it's an unsigned integer.

According to [ranking of implicit conversion sequence in overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences), `unsigned sth => long` and `unsigned sth => int` are equivalent(both conversion). So no winner, all loser, which leads to compilation error.

If you just want to avoid compilation error, convert `intptr_t` to `long` helps. But I think the best way is to use proper type that stands for its meaning. For example, if it's for an address, then just use `uintptr_t` in the beginning, and make it a convention.